# Google Cloud Messaging IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I have made an android application with GCM enabled service in it which works on localhost. User needs to register in order save the device id in the database which would help administrator to send push notifications to the user. Since, the database is on localhost, registration works fine on emulator. But after installing the app on phone, the device does not get registered. Due to unsuccessful registration, the details do not get entered into the database. After searching a bit, found out the problem as the ip address. IP address on pc is different than the address taken by phone even via same router. Is there any solution for this problem? I really need to run the app on the phone and not just on emulator. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using `localhost` on the emulator? That shouldn't work because that would be the emulator itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using localhost to save my database into mysql. And yeah the static ip thing works only on emulator. Need a solution

Comment: You can't use `localhost` on the emulator or a phone if you are trying to communicate with another computer.

Comment: @cricket_007 So, the only solution is to host the site where the database would be saved so that user could register from anywhere at anytime?

Comment: That makes sense, right?. If you are testing in your local network, though, you only need to use the IP address of your server. `localhost` is only the server if you are running code on the server itself

Comment: Thankyou @cricket_007